# Migrating to jquery 1.4

Tags: jquery, upgrade

I would like to upgrade a site from 1.3.2 to 1.4 as I see there are some good performance improvements.

1. Can I simply drop this in or should
   I be concerned about my plugins
   working?
2. Is it backward compatible?
3. What should I be worrying about?

Comment: @oo thanks for the question to let me know there is JQuery 1.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this page: [http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14](http://web.archive.org/web/20110326053440/http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14)  (*cached version from web.archive.org*)

On the bottom there's a list of breaking changes. It will give you an idea if there are issues for you.

There's also a [plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-compat-1.3) which makes jQuery 1.4 compatible with 1.3.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first link have no original content, and the second one is 404. 

Which makes this answer not useful anymore :(

Comment: do you really need to upgrade jquery 1.3 to jquery 1.4 in May 2016?

Answer (score 1):

you should be fine but there are a list of potential issues here:

http://jquery14.com/day-01#backwards

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to try it and see.  jQuery14.com has a [backward compatibility list](http://jquery14.com/day-01#backward), as well as a 1.3-compat plugin you can use to soften the blow.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing the other day and had no issues. One interestng thing is that the site claims that 1.4 no longer defaults `$()` to `$(document).ready` - I do however have such code and it is working fine...